# Sql Query Working in Management Studio but not in program

Tags: asp.net, sql, parameters, drop-down-menu, string

Consider the following query.

```
SELECT     LP.project_id, LP.title, LP.type, LU.NAME, LP.reference, LP.status, LP.correspondence, LP.source, LP.deadline, LP.mstat, LP.num_pages, LP.done, 
                      LP.ss_notes
FROM         LogiCpsProjects AS LP LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      LogiCpsProjectAssignments AS LPA ON LP.project_id = LPA.project_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      LogiCpsUsers AS LU ON LPA.writer_id = LU.ID
WHERE     (LP.status <> 'Closed') AND (LP.status <> 'Cancelled') AND (LP.type LIKE '%' + @type + '%') AND (LP.status LIKE '%' + @status + '%') AND 
                      (LP.source LIKE '%' + @source + '%') AND (CAST(LP.mstat AS VARCHAR(50)) LIKE '%' + @mstat + '%')
ORDER BY LP.project_id
```

In this query I am trying to carry out a search that is based on four parameters namely @type, @status, @source and @mstat. The problem is this query works exactly as it should in Sql Server Management Studio for example if I enter 'Article' in type parameter and leave others blank then it returns all the records with type = 'Article' and if I enter type = 'Article' and status = 'Working' then it returns all records with type = 'Article' and status = 'Working' and so on... In simple words the search is dynamic as user can enter leave all parameters blank or put values in all four. It is working fine in MS but not in actual program.

I am using an SqlDataSource, with same query if I leave all parameters blank it does not return anything, if I enter 1 parameter it still does not return anything, it only return records if I enter all four parameters which means it is not working on blank parameters. To send parameters I am using four drop down lists. All of them look like this one.

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" Width="220px">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="" Text="">All</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Details Pending</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Working</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Awaiting Feedback</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Project Complete (AFB)</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Revision Required Client</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Revision Required Editor</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>To be Cancelled</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Cancelled</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Requirements Not Clear</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Hold</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Closed</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The first item is defined as ALL and it has value and text set to "" (Empty string) so when user select ALL it means all records for that particular parameter.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to whether you're sending null or a blank string for all parameters.  If you run the sql statement "select '%' + null + '%'" in management studio you'll find the result is null, which is not what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 If this is a stored proc, then you can call it from SSMS with nulls and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Sounds like it's a stored proc based on his description.  However, he could run it in management studio and get the same results regardless of whether it's stored proc.  Just gotta make sure you're *really* running the same query by stepping through the code and grabbing the actual query being sent instead of the one you thought it should have been.